# Converting 2D Plot to 3D

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm looking to make do the following with my 2D graph as shown: I want to make a surface plot of gamma vs. J vs h. However I am not sure how to incorporate h. gamma and J are arrays made up of 26 points each. How do I make h fit into this plot if it only has one specific value for each plot?

[image]

Comment: you'll want to use `np.meshgrid` on your x and y parameters, and then refer to this: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

in my final paper I needed to create a 3d graph, on this occasion the graph was a cross of latitude, longitude and radioactive intensity. I used the plotly, check if it's help you [plotly documentation](https://plot.ly/python/3d-surface-plots/).
[My graph created with this biblioteca](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyHMZ.png)